# Build options to bdist

Tags: python, packaging, distutils, setup.py

How do I specify build option:

```
python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
```

when I build rpm package:

```
python setup.py bdist --format=rpm
```

`bdist` seems to be building it all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95 bdist --format=rpm
```